# ActionScript to Javascript cross-compiler

Tags: javascript, actionscript, cross-compiling

I learned ActionScript and FlashBuilder about six months ago and then even more recently heard about Google's GWT and Closure.  But before diving into java, I wanted to find out if there are any projects underway analogous to GWT but which use ActionScript as the development language rather than java. Is there an ActionScript-to-javascript cross-compiler or a tool that can take a SWF and produce javascript communicating with a javascript UI library so the Flash plug-in becomes unnecessary?

Comment: ActionScript is so similar to Javascript that I can't imagine the utility of something like that. And supporting the Flash runtime directly in the browser, well, that's pretty much the dream of HTML5 :-)

Comment: HTML5 aims to add features equivalent to Flash, but it does not aim to support ActionScript directly in browsers.  ActionScript adds type declarations that JavaScript lacks.  So if you want to develop in a type-safe language and deploy to, say, an iPad, an ActionScript-to-JavaScript cross-compile development environment would be a reasonable strategy.  Type-safe development for a node.js based solution would be another reasonable use case.

Comment: I bet that is what you will see coming in a few years if HTML5 really does what it claims. Adobe and Microsoft will not give up on their beloved babies (Flash and Silverlight), and would have no choice but doing what google did with GWT - i.e. compiling their product into javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look to Haxe:

http://haxe.org

Is both a language (pretty close to ActionScript) and a compiler. Writing Haxe code you can compile to SWF, JavaScript, PHP, C++ and Neko.

Worth looking at!

Answer (score 2):

Another one to consider:
http://www.jangaroo.net

Answer (score 0):

http://timwhitlock.info/tag/jaspa/ - A personal project from Tim Whitlock

Answer (score 0):

Check out Zynga's [PlayScript](https://github.com/playscript/playscript-mono) is an open source implementation of ActionScript which targets Mono, C++ and JavaScript.